# How to fit the cell to the values in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the values as below in a cell, with the enter key (return) value in between the string values
It could be that, some time the cell can have more values and some time could be less values. i want to fit the Cell to XYZ and ABC values only (or how many were there in the cell).

I tried Autofit option but didn't work

```
"XYZ <enter key>    
 ABC <enter key>
 <enter key>
 <enter key>
 <enter key>"
```

how I can achieve this using VBA code?

Comment: Can you add some screen shots or image links (upload to Imgur.com) showing the *before* and *after* of what you want? Your description is not quite clear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Autofit VBA method like shown in the following sample ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223697%28v=office.11%29.aspx)):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:I").AutoFit
```

I hope it will help. Regards, AB

Answer (score 0):

The `AutoFit` method should do what you want. Try this:

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.AutoFit
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Or:

```
Range("A1").EntireRow.AutoFit
Range("A1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Etc.

Comment: I tried Autofit and also the options as you mentioned but it didnt work

Comment: Please see my revision. I show pictures of what I *think* you want the output to look like, and the methods I describe have done this.  If this is not correct, please add some screenshots of what you *want* the formatted cell to look like (if you cannot add images here, upload to Imgur.com and just include the URL)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to size the cell *as if* it had no trailing `<enter key>`'s

Ie size

```
"XYZ <enter key>    
 ABC <enter key>
 <enter key>
 <enter key>
 <enter key>"
```

as if it were

```
"XYZ <enter key>    
 ABC"
```

To do this you will need to calculate the required height.  Try this:

```
Sub AdjustCell()
    Dim RwHeight As Long
    Dim NumLines1 As Long, NumLines2 As Long
    Dim a() As String

    With ActiveCell
        If .Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 255
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .EntireRow.AutoFit

        RwHeight = .RowHeight
        a = Split(CStr(.Value), vbLf)
        NumLines1 = UBound(a)
        NumLines2 = NumLines1
        Do While a(NumLines2) = ""
            NumLines2 = NumLines2 - 1
        Loop
        .EntireRow.RowHeight = (NumLines2 + 2) / (NumLines1 + 2) * RwHeight
    End With
End Sub
```

This assumes that the active cell contains the largest cell (by height) in the row